# Autosave is always disabled in Microsoft Office products

Tags: microsoft-office

I've always noticed that the AutoSave option is always disabled. I've looked up in the settings and website on how to enable this, and it seems enabled in settings but I'm always curious to why this is there if I can't change it.

What does this AutoSave specifically do and why can't I use it?

[image: Snippet of AutoSave on Microsoft Office toolbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autosave is enabled for files which are synchronized with the cloud, thus they have a backup in OneDrive. Else, it is disabled.